# Value of type '...' does not conform to '...' in assignment

Tags: swift, xcode, interface, protocols

In a project we are facing a weird problem with prodocols not get picked up by xcode.

We defined the following protocol within the regular app:

```
protocol VCDismisser: class {
    func dismiss(animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?)
}

extension UIViewController: VCDismisser {}
```

Within a random ViewController we define:

```
class RandomVC: UIViewController {
   lazy var vcDismisser: VCDismisser = self
}
```

Within a test part of the XCProject we want define the following:

```
class MockDismisser: VCDismisser {
    var dismissCalled = false
    func dismiss(animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        dismissCalled = true
    }
}
```

And in any testcase for the RandomVC we want to "inject" our mock:

```
func testSuccessfulLoginDismisses() {
    let dismisser = MockDismisser()
    randomVC.vcDismisser = dismisser
    randomVC.viewDidLoad()
    mockviewModel.loggedIn.value = LoginState.successful
    XCTAssertTrue(dismisser.dismissCalled)
}
```

XCode is now getting pretty bonkers and always tells us:

[image]

What do we do wrong here and how do we fix that xcode is accepting it as the right type?

Comment: What happens when you click on `Fix`? And **never** call methods containing `will`, `should` and `did` yourself. Don't do that. Those methods are exclusively called by the framework.

Comment: It'll add `dismisser as! VCDismisser` but that doesn't change the error message and i can add `as! VCDismisser` forever by clicking `Fix`

Comment: What happens if you change `lazy var vcDismisser = self` to `lazy var vcDismisser: VCDismisser = self`

Comment: @rmaddy good point thats a mistake in the question. It is actually with the Type declaration.

Comment: I just tried this out myself in a playground and it did not show this error. Have you tried shutting down Xcode and re-launching it?

Comment: @Ash I've done that but the issue was something else I'll explain in an answer

Comment: Not a circular reference to self, by any chance? ;) I just noticed what you're doing in the RandomVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason here was something which wasn't obvious within my question. The File containing the extension and the protocol had the target membership of test and the application causing xcode getting confused. Removing the target membership of test did resolve the issue.

Comment: Yep, that'd do it, although I gotta say I'm not fond of the idea of an object that holds a lazy reference to itself by default.

Comment: @Ash i agree but it's more or less the best option to make presenting / dismissing / segueing calls testable or do you have a better solution to this? There shouldn't be a cycle in memory by this.

Comment: Create your mock as a subclass of the view controller and override the functions you want to check for? A bit annoying if you want to check multiple functions I guess, since you may need one for each function you want to test. I also get the feeling you might be able to do something with the completion block of that function, but I don't have the time right now to come up with a full solution, sorry.

Comment: @Ash thank you for the idea I always try to find something better here 

Answer (score -1):

Try to cast Mock dissmisser as VCDismisser:

```
let dismisser: VCDismisser = MockDismisser()
```